# Laplace Transform of Stopping Time of Brownian Motion

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let W represent a standard Brownian Motion in one dimension. For some $b > 0$, let $S_b$ denote the first time that $|W_t| = a$. How do we show that the Laplace transform of $S_b$ is 
$$E[\exp(\lambda S_b)] = \cosh(s\sqrt{2\lambda})^{-1}$$

My intuition is that this can be obtained by applying optional stopping theorem to a martingale.

Comment: Any idea what kind of martingale you might want to consider?

Comment: I'm not really sure? Some-type of exponential martingale?

Comment: Well, there aren't so many exponential martingales for Brownian motion, are there? Why not give it a try and see what you get?

Comment: @saz I actually considered the martingale $e^{\theta{B_{t}}-(\theta^{2}t/2)}$ and using the optional stopping theorem and DCT, I concluded that $E_{0}[e^{\theta{B_{S_{b}}}-(\theta^{2}S_{b}/2)}]=1$

Comment: How does one obtain the $\cosh$? is it from $\exp(\theta{B}_{S_{b}})$?

Comment: @user135520 See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1507985/36150) and also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1078246/36150)